# CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates - Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, docusignapi

I am attempting to create a DocuSign envelope from a template document using the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method, available within their v3 SOAP API web service. This is being instantiated from a asp.NET v4.0 web site.

Upon calling the method armed with the required parameter objects being passed in. I am recieving an exception from the web service, basically telling me that the Template ID is not a valid GUID.

```
669393: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

Line 14889:        
Line 14890:        public DocuSignDSAPI.EnvelopeStatus CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(DocuSignDSAPI.TemplateReference[] TemplateReferences, DocuSignDSAPI.Recipient[] Recipients, DocuSignDSAPI.EnvelopeInformation EnvelopeInformation, bool ActivateEnvelope) {
Line 14891:            return base.Channel.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(TemplateReferences, Recipients, EnvelopeInformation, ActivateEnvelope);
Line 14892:        }
Line 14893:
```

The template reference, a guid. Must be specified as the "Template" string property against TemplateReference object. This is then added to a dynamic array of TemplateReferences, which is one of the input parameters of the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method.

> Actual template GUID: f37b4d64-54e3-4723-a6f1-a4120f0e9695

I am building up my template reference object using the following function that i wrote to try and make the functionality reusable:

```
Private Function GetTemplateReference(ByVal TemplateID As String) As TemplateReference

    Dim templateReference As New TemplateReference
    Dim guidTemplateID As Guid

    With TemplateReference

        .TemplateLocation = TemplateLocationCode.Server

        If Guid.TryParse(TemplateID, guidTemplateID) Then
            .Template = guidTemplateID.ToString
        End If

    End With

    Return TemplateReference

End Function
```

The TemplateID is being passed in from a appSetting configuration value at the time of the TemplateReferences array instantiation like so...

```
templateReferences = New TemplateReference() {GetTemplateReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DocuSignTemplate_Reference"))}
            recipients = New Recipient() {AddRecipient("myself@work.email", "My Name")}

            envelopeInformation = CreateEnvelopeInformation()
            envelopeStatus = client.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(templateReferences, recipients, envelopeInformation, True)
```

As you can see from my GetTemplateReference function I am also parsing the GUID before setting it back as a string so i know its valid. The template is managed and stored at the DocuSign end, hence specifying the document location.

I am referring to their own documentation: 
[CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates.htm)

Why oh why is the method not liking my Template ID? I can successfully use their REST API to call the same method, using their own code samples. Worst case I can make use of this but would rather interact with the web service as I would need to construct all the relevent requests in either XML or JSON.

I would really appreciate if someone could perhaps shed some light on this problem.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Can you post a trace of the data that you're passing? It looks like you're probably missing an AccountID or some other GUID

Answer (score 1):

Andrew might be spot on with the `AccountId` mention - are you setting the `AccountId` in the envelope information object?  Also, have you seen the DocuSign SOAP SDK up on Github?  That has 5 sample SOAP projects including one MS.NET project.  The .NET project is in C# not Visual Basic, but still I think it will be helpful to you.  Check out the SOAP SDK here:

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

For instance, here is the test function for the `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates()` function:

```
    public void CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesTest()
    {
        // Construct all the recipient information
        DocuSignWeb.Recipient[] recipients = HeartbeatTests.CreateOneSigner();
        DocuSignWeb.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[] finalRoleAssignments = new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[1];
        finalRoleAssignments[0] = new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        finalRoleAssignments[0].RoleName = recipients[0].RoleName;
        finalRoleAssignments[0].RecipientID = recipients[0].ID;

        // Use a server-side template -- you could make more than one of these
        DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference templateReference = new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference();
        templateReference.TemplateLocation = DocuSignWeb.TemplateLocationCode.Server;
        // TODO: replace with template ID from your account
        templateReference.Template = "server template ID";
        templateReference.RoleAssignments = finalRoleAssignments;

        // Construct the envelope information
        DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = _accountId;
        envelopeInfo.Subject = "create envelope from templates test";
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "testing docusign creation services";

        // Create draft with all the template information
        DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeStatus status = _apiClient.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference[] { templateReference },
            recipients, envelopeInfo, false);

        // Confirm that the envelope has been assigned an ID
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(status.EnvelopeID);
        Console.WriteLine("Status for envelope {0} is {1}", status.EnvelopeID, status.Status);
    }
```

This code calls other sample functions in the SDK which I have not included, but hopefully this helps shed some light on what you're doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when you don't set up the field AccountId. This field can be retrieved from your account. In Docusign's console go to Preferences / API and look here

[**Where to find AccountID Guid in Docusign's Console**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3c8b.png)

Use API Account ID (which is in GUID format) and you should be OK.